# Use Imagemagick to crop large images to a specific aspect ratio and then resize them

Tags: imagemagick, crop, image-resizing

I have a bunch of high-resolution images from Unsplash and,

1. First need to crop to a 16:9 aspect ratio (from the center), and then,
2. Resize them to 2560x1440px.

How do I do this using `Imagemagick` on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you need for a single image:

```
magick INPUT.JPG -gravity center -extent 16:9 -resize 2560x1440 RESULT.JPG
```

---

If you want to do lots, you could use a `bash` loop:

```
for f in *.jpg *.png ; do
   magick "$f" -gravity center -extent 16:9 -resize 2560x1440 "$f"
done
```

---

If you have thousands, you could use **homebrew** to install **GNU Parallel** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

Then get them done in parallel using all your CPU cores with:

```
parallel --bar magick {} -gravity center -extent 16:9 -resize 2560x1440 {} ::: *.jpg *.png
```

---

If you have hundreds of thousands, or millions, that will overflow the ARG_MAX, so you will need to feed the filenames on `stdin` like this:

```
find . -iname \*.png -print0 | parallel -0 magick {} -gravity center -extent 16:9 -resize 2560x1440 {}
```